# How do I set a new array to myController.arrangedObjects?

Tags: cocoa, object

I am trying to manipulate the values of the arrangedObjects in my array controller.  So far I have been able to pull the objects into a temp array and manipulate them but I can not set the array to my array controller.  My temp array is an NSMutableArray and the arrangedObjects is of class NSArray.  Is it because it is not mutable that I can't assign a new array to it?

Additional info:  the array controller has two keys, an NSString and a float.  These are displayed in an NSTableView.  I am currently pulling only the float key values and trying to set them back in the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSObjectController's setContent: method to assign a new array to your controller.

It sounds like your array controller contains an array of NSDictionaries.  If you instead filled it with a custom class of your own, or by using Core Data, you could manipulate their values in place, eliminating the need to recreate the content array every time.

Comment: Switching from NSDictionary to NSMutableDictionary would have the same effect.